# Wait for 3rd party plugin $(...).click() AJAX call to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, async-await

We work on a 3rd party opensource CMS. **We cannot edit any piece of code of it in any sense**.

There're forms to fill which we design for the users. Those forms have section tabs. Those section tabs are implemented with a plugin.
Instead of loading all form tabs content on page load, it basically loads dynamically via AJAX when tabs are clicked. Classic.

I created a button on a "CUSTOM HTML pill" on the form (which lets you inject HTML+JS+CSS), which on click basically triggers a click on every TAB on the designed form. This way, it loads everything on page (when loaded, just hidden from that moment on, and not ajax is called again for that specific  clicked tab).

Then I serialize all the form and send it to a Python Flask server via an AJAX call made by me.

**THE PROBLEM:**

As I said, before ajax call to Flask, I trigger click to every tab to load on page all form fields there,  because this way I sent ALL the real form to Flask, if not, only some form pieces goes to the request.

If every goes fine, it goes as expected. But tab content ajax load is ASYNC, so sometimes it doesn't finish and Flask receives incomplete form.

**THE QUESTION:**

On my custom button click, how can I force clicking to every tab, **and wait for ALL the async requests made** (programmed on the 3rd party plugin not editable) to finish and finally, make my call to Flask with the complete Form serialized data?
Cannot use promises (await, $.when()) because tab click makes a common `$.ajax()` call but not with a `return $.ajax()`.

```
//Pseudocode:
mybutton.click(
  $(allTabs).click() //this creates a cascade of ajax calls loading every tab data from server. Just once (first time)

  WHEN ALL PREVIOUS ASYNC CALLS FINISHED AND ONLY THOSE:

  let FORMDATA = serialize(FULL FORM WITH EVERY TAB LOADED)

  $.ajax(post call to my Python Flask, FORMDATA)

)
```

Comment: There's no way to hook in to an async request made from another location in the JS code. What you could do instead, assuming the AJAX call updates the DOM, is to use a MutationObserver. This will raise an event when an element in the DOM is changed so that you know the AJAX is finished, ready for you to continue on with whatever tasks you require.

Comment: If it is truly a jQuery `$.ajax` call, you could possibly use a [global ajax event handler like `ajaxComplete`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), but you'd have to know what calls are made in order to know what was complete.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's true. My 'no way to do this' statement was a little too far reaching, however the other point remains

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure, I wasn't actually responding to your comment, just throwing out an idea. It would be cumbersome to track the completion of exact requests that way, so the MutationObserver seems like a better idea anyway.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah... I guess maybe this is the approach, but I don't really like it much... And it is horrible, because it doesn't play with "display" propperty o similar, but with "left" and displacing elements on screen with a transition... :(